# How to re-enter my virtual environment using cmd in windows

Tags: django, python-3.x, virtual-environment

I have created a virtual environment for django using cmd

```
 pip install virtualenvwrapper-win

 mkvirtualenv test
```

and here I have installed Django using

```
 pip install django
```

But suppose I close my cmd prompt and restart it. What is the command to re-enter in the (test) environment that I have created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the package `virtualenvwrapper-win`, then you can use the options described in [this part of the docs](https://github.com/davidmarble/virtualenvwrapper-win/#main-commands):

> `workon [<name>]`
>
> If `<name>` is specified, activate the environment named `<name>` (change the working virtualenv to `<name>`). If a project directory has
>   been defined, we will change into it. If no argument is specified,
>   list the available environments. One can pass additional option `-c`
>   after virtualenv name to cd to virtualenv directory if no projectdir
>   is set.

Answer (score 1):

To reactivate the virtual environment:
Virtualenvname\Scripts\activate.bat
Eg:testing\Scripts\activate.bat
This will opens your virtual environment to use.

Answer (score 0):

> To create a virtual environment open command prompt/terminal and navigate to the directory where you want to create your Django project. Let’s say we want to create our project at 'user/hp/' then we’ll navigate to the 'user/hp/' and then type the command below.

> Install the virtual environment

[image]

> Create a virtual environment

```
C:\Users\hp\mkvirtualenv jangoProject
```

[image]

> To activate env type the below command.

```
C:\Users\hp\jangoProject\Scripts\activate
```

[image]

> To deactivate env type the below command

[image]

> To create a new project type below code

C:\User\hp\django-admin startproject learn1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to re entering the same virtual environment created earlier one should firstly change to the directory where virtual environment is created using the CD(directory).
and later change in to the project directory and then change to SCRIPTS
and at that moment use the command ACTIVATE to activate the virtual environment.

steps:

- cd #project name
- cd scripts
- cd ..
- use command #activate

follow the above steps to reactivate virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

To activate previously created environment, just type the following command in your anaconda prompt:

```bash
conda activate 'name_of_the_environment'
```

Voila! You are now on your virtual environment.